# ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema using Lambda

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Instead of using a `query`, I tried using the `get-item`, but when calling it in the lambda function, I get a `ValidationError`. What did I miss here?

Here's my definition:

```yaml
MyTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: secondId
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema: 
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: secondId
          KeyType: RANGE
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
```

This works and got the result when calling it from the console/command line.

```sh
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name MyTable --key "{\"id\":{\"S\":\"LOREM_IPSUM\"}, \"secondId\":{\"S\":\"nulla mollit quis\"}}"
```

But using the lambda code below, it throws an error:

"The provided key element does not match the schema"

```js
const params: GetItemInput = {
            "TableName": “MyTable”,
            "Key": {
                "id" : { "S": idValue },
                "secondId": { "S": secondIdValue }
            }
        }

const data = this.client.get(params).promise();
```

This solves the problem by removing the GetItemInput type. I don't get why it has to be removed.

```js
const params = {
            "TableName": “MyTable”,
            "Key": {
                "id" : { "S": idValue },
                "secondId": { "S": secondIdValue }
            }
        }

const data = this.client.get(params).promise();
```